Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;email&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039;
I am trying to get specific data from the database by using column phone_numberwhen a user clicks a link but I am getting this error:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;email&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039; (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `password_reset_tokens` where `email` is null limit 1)

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('password_reset_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('phone_number')->primary();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_reset_tokens');
    }
};

public function resetPasswordConfirm(Request $request)
    {   
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required|exists:users,phone_number',
            'password' => 'required|min:5',
        ]);
        
        $response = Password::broker('users')->reset(
            [
                'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'password_confirmation' => $request->password_confirmation,
                'token' => $request->token,
            ],
            function ($user, $password) {
                $user->forceFill([
                    'password' => Hash::make($password),
                ])->save();
            }
        );

        if ($response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Пароль успешно сброшен']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Не удалось сбросить пароль. Пожалуйста, проверьте введенные данные.']);
        }
    }


I don't see any query with an "email" column in your code.

Please confirm your table schema 'email' column are present as you used in your code logic

What is Password::broker()? I suspect the problem is in there.
